# Get Commentor IP When Marking Comment As Spam

Tags: plugin-development, comment-form, spam, comments

What I am trying to do is create a list of IP addresses each time I click Spam on a comment. The only issue I have now is, how do I get the commentors IP address inside this function.

This is what I am working with... It ties into the onclick event of the Spam button.

```
add_action('transition_comment_status', 'report_spam', 1);
function report_spam($new_status){
    if($new_status == 'spam'){
        //do something here with IP
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing 2 parameters in your function `report_spam`. Also the priority should not be 1. Try the code below.

```
add_action('transition_comment_status', 'report_spam', 10, 3);
function report_spam($new_status,  $old_status, $comment){
    if($new_status == 'spam'){
        var_dump($comment->comment_author_IP);
        die;
    } 
}
```

I've set `die` so that you can check and manipulate what you want.